# Strange int value returned in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I'm modifying polymorphism example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) to test multiple inheritance. When I run the following code, I get a strange value "15794192" printed on console where I expect 20 as a result. What is wrong? I appreciate your opinion.

I've tried to workaround the errors that are caused by problems in multiple inheritance, and come up with this code that doesn't make any build error. The issue I'm discussing may not be rooted in multiple inheritance but I'm not yet sure. The original example in the web page cited works fine needless to say.

(Environment) Ubuntu 12.04, cmake 2.8.7 run on eclipse Indigo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CPolygon //: public CShape
{
protected:
  int width, height;
public:
  void set_values(int a, int b)
  {
    width = a;
    height = b;
  }
  virtual int area(void) =0;
  void printarea(void)
  {
    cout << this->area() << endl;
  }
};

class CustomPolygon : public CPolygon
{
public:
  int customParam;
  void printarea(void)
  {
    this->CPolygon::printarea();
  }
};

class Rectangle : public CPolygon // This class should be concrete.
{
public:
  int area(void)
  {
    return (width * height);
  }
  void printarea(void)
  {
    this->CPolygon::printarea();
  }
};

class CustomSquare : public CustomPolygon, Rectangle  // Concrete class
{
public:
  int area()
  {
    this->Rectangle::area();
  }
  void printarea(void)
  {
    this->Rectangle::printarea();
  }
  void set_values(int a, int b)
  {
    this->Rectangle::set_values(a, b);
  }
};

int main()
{
  CustomSquare *cs = new CustomSquare();
  cs->CustomSquare::set_values(4, 5);
  cs->CustomSquare::printarea();
  return 0;
}
```

---

(Update 8/14/12) Thanks to advices, now I'm able to avoid explicitly declaring the functions from which super class to be used by using `virtual inheritance`. Updated code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CPolygon
{
protected:
  int width, height;
public:
  void set_values(int a, int b)
  {
    width = a;
    height = b;
  }
  virtual int area(void) =0;
  void printarea(void)
  {
    cout << this->area() << endl;
  }
};

class CustomPolygon : virtual public CPolygon
{
public:
  int customParam;
};

class Rectangle : virtual public CPolygon
{
public:
  int area(void)
  {
    return (width * height);
  }
};

class CustomSquare : public CustomPolygon, Rectangle
{
};

int main()
{
  CustomSquare *cs = new CustomSquare();
  cs->CustomSquare::set_values(4, 5);
  cs->CustomSquare::printarea();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that the example will be very enlightening... I am quite familiar with C++ and inheritance and it is not simple to follow and understand what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I understand what you're saying but not sure how NOT enlightening this example is...Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, my point is that the example is convoluted mixing the basics of OO (virtual function dispatch) with explicit calls. The main problem is that instead of working with a simple type hierarchy, you are using multiple inheritance and hitting the diamond problem (the same base type is a base through different paths in the hierarchy, creating multiple subobjects of the same type. This type of hierarchies is not common in real world scenarios, and when they happen, they are usually handled with *virtual inheritance* (so that there is a single *base* (`CPolygon`) object in your hierarchy.

Comment: ... that is, semantically `CustomSquare` does not contain *two* different `CPolygon`, rather a single one although through different bases. Now, if the hierarchy did not contain the *diamond* or if inheritance was virtual, then `CustomSquare` would not need to implement `area` manually dispatching to the `Rectangle` implementation, as the overrider in `Rectangle` would already be the *final overrider*. The example is unrealistic, and you might have come to the conclusion that you needed to provide `area` in `CustomSquare` (as the compiler requires you to), but that is not an issue of ...

Comment: .. inheritance, but rather of the *strange* design that you used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the function `area` in `CustomSquare`, you don't return any value!

I''m not familiar with Eclipse, but I'm pretty sure there is a way to enable warnings for situations like that.
In g++ it would be the `-Wreturn-type` switch, or `-Wall`

Comment: Thank you, now it works. My bad... (I'll accept this as answer after system allows to do so).

Answer (score 10):

You need to return something from the `CustomSquare::area()` method:

```
int area()
{
  return this->Rectangle::area();
}
```

You should also consider using virtual inheritance, since you have a case of diamond inheritance:

```
class CustomPolygon : virtual public CPolygon {};

class Rectangle : virtual public CPolygon {};
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding virtual at those 2 class declaration yields another wrong value (39272464) ...And, forgot to mention but I want `Rectangle` to be concrete class.

Comment: @IsaacS Sorry, that was not the cause of the error. It is the missing `return` issue.